# Edit and complete string with foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

How can I complete my variable with each loop?

```
$string = "Our products are shoes, pants, shirts."
$products = get_post_meta( post_id, 'products', true );
$matches = get_post_meta( post_id, 'matches', true );

$newPhrase = '';

foreach ($matches as $match){
    $id = searchForId($match, $products); // searching for the right id
    $newPhrase = str_replace($match, $products[$id]['sku'], $string);
}

// $newPhrase should be "Our Products are 3, 4, 9."
```

Although it changes the variable with each foreach but then it starts always again and takes the old string. for example: "our Products are shoes, pants, 9."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have here is that you are re-saving the string back into the same variable. Instead, you're saving it into `$newPhrase`.

So when the loop runs again, it's adjusting the old *unchanged* string again, and then saving that as the `$newPhrase` variable - overwriting what you did during the previous loop iteration. Which is why you end up with only the last variable changed.

Instead of grabbing the old string everytime, instead grab the string that was adjusted, like this:

```
$string = "Our products are shoes, pants, shirts."
$products = get_post_meta( post_id, 'products', true );
$matches = get_post_meta( post_id, 'matches', true );

$newPhrase = $string;

foreach ($matches as $match){
    $id = searchForId($match, $products); // searching for the right id
    $newPhrase = str_replace($match, $products[$id]['sku'], $newPhrase);
}
```

[Here's a working php fiddle](https://eval.in/1019329) (*slightly adjusted, because I don't have access to your product meta*).

Comment: Thank you. It can be so easy. ;-)

Comment: Hahaha anytime @desmeit it's the small things that evade us best :)